# Service name missing in task, present in powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-services, scheduled-tasks

I have worked on a powershell script to check if certain important services are running on the server and email me the results. When I test the script and run it in powershell, the emails come through correctly. However when I set up the task on the server and have it run the script, the emails that arrive are now all missing the service names.

Email when the script is run in powershell:

> At 12-11-20 11:06, the [service] is ALL GOOD on [server].

Email when the script is run through tasks:

> At 12-11-20 11:00, the is on [server].

(services and server names redacted)

Any ideas on what syntax I'm missing that it works in the testing, but not in the actual execution?

My script code (with some details redacted):

```
$DateTime = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yy hh:mm"

#Check if service is running
$servName = "[service I need to check]"
$serv = Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq $servName}

$Subject =$Serv.Name + " check on [server]"

If ($serv.Status -ne "Running") {
    $Body = "At $DateTime, the " + $serv.DisplayName + " service is " + $serv.Status + " on [server]."
}
Else { $Body = "At $DateTime, the " + $serv.DisplayName + " is ALL GOOD on [server]." }
[location]\EmailAlert.ps1 -Recipient me@work.com -Subject $Subject -Body $Body

$servName = "[another service to check]"
$serv = Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq $servName}

$Subject =$Serv.Name + " check on [server]"

If ($serv.Status -ne "Running") {
    $Body = "At $DateTime, the " + $serv.DisplayName + " service is " + $serv.Status + " on [server]."
}
Else { $Body = "At $DateTime, the " + $serv.DisplayName + " is ALL GOOD on [server]." }
[location]\EmailAlert.ps1 -Recipient me@work.com -Subject $Subject -Body $Body
```

Comment: `$serv` could be a collection of multiple services. Depending on the PowerShell version (v2?), You might see a different result.

Comment: Hmm... I did a Get-Services list of everything on the server and used the full display names of the exact services I wanted which looked distinct. How can I check if the task is grabbing too many?

Comment: `@($serv).count`. What happens if you do e.g. `$serv[0].DisplayName`?

Comment: Well if I do $serv[0].DisplayName I continue to get emails from running it in powershell, but now I get no emails at from running the task.

Comment: Looks like the line `Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq $servName}` doesn't find any service with that displayname. Perhaps the locale settings on the server are different than your settings. Try to not use the **DisplayName**, but use the service **Name** instead.

Comment: I'm running it all on the server including the powershell test so shouldn't they all have the same locale settings? Why would running it on the server's task suddenly fail to find the service when running it in the server's powershell work?